# What's the difference between these two return functions (using colon or normal format)? Thanks

Tags: javascript

```
var budgetController = (function() {
var x = 23;

var add = function(a) {
    return x + a;
}

return {
    publicTest: function(b) {
        return add(b);
    }
}
})();
```

---

```
var budgetController = (function() {
var x = 23;

var add = function(a) {
    return x + a;
}

return {
    publicTest(b) {
        return add(b);
    }
}
})();
```

I'm learning an online course about Module and Closure. I'm confused with these two style of function format. If I call budgetController.publicTest(5); 
Both seems work.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Regarding closures, there is no difference at all

Comment: The function inside `return` is called method which is publically available when `budgetController ` instance is created using the `new` keyword. Whereas, the function above the return is private to `budgetController` and can only be accessed inside this controller. This is just to bring some OO concept into JavaScript but now in ES5+ there are classes available instead going with your approach.